# OpenCV/Java - Use Computer Screen for OpenCV's Video Processing

Tags: java, opencv, awt

I'm working on a Java or Scala program that does the following things:

1) Detect

- Continuously monitor particular dynamic section of the screen (i.g. x: [0, 500], y: [0, 500])

2) Process

- Implement custom image pattern detector for particular image patterns (i.e. human face or etc)
- Trigger custom listener to fire if particular pattern is detected

3) Action

- Use Java's AWT library to perform a click in fixed location of the screen

Looks like OpenCV/Java AWT seems like a reasonble choice to accomplish this task. If there are better tools/language to accomplish this, please suggest those as well.

My questions are the following:

- OpenCV supports video processing as well as image processing. In order to efficiently accomplish detection, I don't want to keep taking screenshots of the screen every x seconds and run OpenCV to process the image. Is it possible to make OpenCV to process particular section of my screen as if it is a processing video?
- OpenCV is originally written in C/C++ and I am having hard time finding examples for implementing custom image pattern defection sample codes. Can anyone share where I can find Java/Scala example codes regarding this?

Any suggestions with examples/references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is very broad and likely to be closed as a result. Do you have any more specific questions you could limit this single question to? Remember that it is indeed appropriate to ask separate questions for different sub-questions. With that said, the specific question about where examples can be found could also fall under off-topic as asking for off-site resources.

Comment: 1:) unfortunately os-dependant, and not at all handled from opencv. 2:) no problem 3:) os-dependant again, good luck. - "Looks like OpenCV/Java AWT seems like a reasonble choice " - hmmm. actually, you rather have to interface your os from c++, not java, i guess.